# How to draw an arrow inside a disk?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I would like to draw an arrow inside a plain disk. Or more precisely, I would like to remove the shape of an arrow from a disk (we could see through the disk where the arrow is drawn), like this one:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

So far I have drawn a disk and an arrow using the following code:

```
// Disk
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(95, 62, 23, 23))
color2.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()


// Arrow
var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(95.5, 75.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(106.5, 65.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(117.5, 75.5))
color3.setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()
```

But it's not what I'm looking for as the arrow is on top of the disk, so obviously I cannot see what's behind the disk.

Comment: Did you try this [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage] set];

Comment: try `CAShapeLayer`. You can clip or mask via `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need to draw such complicated shape with code, you can use `.png` assets to replace.

But if you still want to draw it. Here is what I did with `CALayer` in Xcode6.3 Playground

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let sequence = [
CGPointMake(56, 22),
CGPointMake(104, 78),
CGPointMake(99, 82),
CGPointMake(57, 30),
CGPointMake(16, 82),
CGPointMake(11, 78)
]


let diskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))
diskLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath
diskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let arrowPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(arrowPath, nil, 11,78)
CGPathAddLines(arrowPath, nil, sequence, 6)
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(arrowPath, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))


arrowLayer.path = arrowPath
arrowLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
diskLayer.mask = arrowLayer


var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))
view.layer.addSublayer(diskLayer)


XCPShowView("sample view", view)
```

[image]

Use mask, you would get the transparent arrow.

Try it yourself~

Comment: Thanks. Just a question: why do you put the diskLayer as a subLayer and not as the mask for the layer? (or said another way, why when you put it as the mask for the layer, you won't see anything unless you apply a backgroundColor on the view?)

Comment: @Nico Cause you don't have anything in the layer, so when you mask it, there is still nothing there.

Comment: Actually there is something I don't really understand. `var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))
diskLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath`. Why do you need to this as you're drawing the circle in the other path?

Comment: @Nico no, the circle is drawn here

Comment: Then what about `CGPathAddEllipseInRect(arrowPath, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))`?

Comment: @Nico This line is used to reverse the mask

Comment: @Nico check out the evenodd rule of CALayer

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill your arrow with blending. Try this for your arrow drawing-

```
// Arrow
var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(95.5, 75.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(106.5, 65.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(117.5, 75.5))
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
bezierPath.fillWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeSourceIn, alpha:1)
```